# Bluebird promisify mongoose group by

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model in mongoose

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

function toLower (v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
}

var Signup = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, set: toLower },
  position: { type: String },
  area: String,
  companySize: Number,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Signup', Signup);
```

I would like to group by created (date formatted to day) and count the number of _ids.

I'm new to mongoose and bluebird... Could anyone provide me with an example? Thx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get exactly what I wanted:

```
SignupModel
  .aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $week: "$created" },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }
    }
  ])
  .execAsync()
  .then(responseWithResult(res))
  .catch(handleError(res));
```

=> Groups by created (week) and sums them